# How to connect Amazon Product Advertising API with Strapi to fetch data from Amazon PAAPI and show it in my web-site?

Tags: strapi, amazon-product-advertising-api, amazon-paapi, gatsby-strapi

I have to fetch, list of products (along with each product's details) from "Amazon Product Advertising API", based on a specific selected Category and show it in my web-site(in Gatsby)?

Can we connect "Amazon Product Advertising API" with "Strapi" and directly fetch data from Amazon PAAPI and show it in my web-site?

If it's possible, then can anybody please share the steps?

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely something you can do using controllers: https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization/controllers.html

What is the reason why you'd like to pass this content through Strapi rather than requesting the Amazon Product Advertising API from Gatsby? Is the goal to hide the Amazon API keys?